# Best open source in memory java application for implementing Trie

Tags: java, memory

I want to implement a high speed in memory implementation of Trie to create backend to  auto suggestion / spell checker.
Is there already some good implementation based on in memory implementations like hazlecast.
Also which java open source tool is best suggested for these kind of usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a plain NavigableSet like TreeSet.  Its built in and supports range searches.

```
 NavigableSet<String> words = new TreeSet<String>();
 // add words.
 String startsWith = ...
 SortedSet<String> matching = words.subSet(startsWith, startsWith + '\uFFFF');
```

If you want something more memory efficient you can use an array.

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("aa");
words.add("ab");
words.add("ac");
words.add("ba");
Collections.sort(words);

String startsWith = "a";
int first = Collections.binarySearch(words, startsWith);
int last = Collections.binarySearch(words, startsWith.concat("\uFFFF"));
if (first < 0) first = ~first;
if (last < 0) last = ~last - 1;
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    System.out.println(words.get(i));
}
```